# When I open Terminal it says command alias not found and closes

Tags: 12.10, command-line, alias

I was messing around in Terminal (bad idea, I know, but I'm usually pretty good with it) and now it does what the title says. I know about pressing Control-C to stop it from running, but how do I just stop it running the command without pressing Ctrl-C?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you apply any changes to your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile` files? Are you able to log in to a virtual terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`)? (go back with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7`).

Comment: No, I don't think I did. (thanks for such a quick reply :) )

Comment: Then please explain "messing around in Terminal". Also, can you install another terminal application and see if that works? (`xterm`, `Konsole`, etc.)

Comment: just checked with virtual terminal, same thing. same with xterm, too. And I was using this guide to mount an Android MTP device, modified for a Kindle Fire. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you might have copied and pasted these lines from the guide as-is:

```
echo “alias android-connect=\”mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\”" >> ~/.bashrc

echo “alias android-disconnect=\”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\”" >> ~/.bashrc
```

With those special speech marks (also known as smart quotes) having a different meaning to the terminal than regular speech marks, the commands are radically altered from the original intent.

I suggest you check the end of ~/.bashrc for those suspect alias lines, remove them if they are there, and reopen the terminal.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks so much, this fixed it! Man, five years of Ubuntu and I couldn't figure that out, time to brush up.

Comment: Important lesson for @Rain: Don't just run random commands from tutorials! And I was right in my first comment, but I must have missed this part of the tutorial. So, good find by IlluminAce here! :)